# Button onclick event doesn't fire in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I don't know what is the problem in this code.

There are two input fields which are used for two variables to add, subtract, multiply and divide and 4 buttons (one each for add, subtract, multiply, and divide), but when I click on them nothing happens.

```
<h1>Calculator</h1>
<input id="f1" />
<input id="f2" />
<button id="add">Add</button>
<button id="sub">Sub</button>
<button id="multi">Multi</button>
<button id="div">Div</button>
```

```
var f1, f2, result;
document.getElementById("add").onclick=function{
    f1= document.getElementById("f1").value;
    f2= document.getElementById("f2").value;
    result = return f1+f2;
}
document.getElementById("sub").onclick=function{
    f1= document.getElementById("f1").value;
    f2= document.getElementById("f2").value;
    result = return f1-f2;
}
document.getElementById("multi").onclick=function{
    f1= document.getElementById("f1").value;
    f2= document.getElementById("f2").value;
    result = return f1*f2;
}
document.getElementById("div").onclick=function{
    f1= document.getElementById("f1").value;
    f2= document.getElementById("f2").value;
    result = return f1/f2;
}
if(result!=null)
alert("Result = "+result);
```

Comment: Check your syntax for errors here http://jshint.com

Comment: their is no method name you have given and not called on button click at all...then how do u expect to something happen on button click?

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE it is not necessary to give method name, i have given id instead so function will be called when the button related to that ID is clicked...

Comment: YES I AGREE! :) your syntax of calling function is incorrect! function{} must be replaced with function(){} right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some mistakes and syntax errors:

1. The `function` need `()`:

   ```
   onclick = function () {}
   ```
2. There is no need to use `return` in this case, just store the result into your variable:

   ```
   result = f1+f2;
   ```
3. You should convert your textbox values into numbers:

   ```
   f1 = document.getElementById("f1").value * 1;
   ```
4. You should show the result in each `onclick`, not at the end your script.

```js
var f1, f2, result;
document.getElementById("add").onclick=function(){
 f1= document.getElementById("f1").value * 1;
 f2= document.getElementById("f2").value * 1;
 result =  f1+f2;
 alert("Result = "+result);
}
document.getElementById("sub").onclick=function(){
 f1= document.getElementById("f1").value * 1;
 f2= document.getElementById("f2").value * 1;
 result =  f1-f2;
 alert("Result = "+result);
}
document.getElementById("multi").onclick=function(){
 f1= document.getElementById("f1").value * 1;
 f2= document.getElementById("f2").value * 1;
 result =  f1*f2;
 alert("Result = "+result);
}
document.getElementById("div").onclick=function(){
 f1= document.getElementById("f1").value * 1;
 f2= document.getElementById("f2").value * 1;
 result =  f1/f2;
 alert("Result = "+result);
}
```

```html
<h1>Calculator</h1>
<input id="f1" />
<input id="f2" />
<button id="add">Add</button>
<button id="sub">Sub</button>
<button id="multi">Multi</button>
<button id="div">Div</button>
```

Comment: hey @ROX! nice to see the "Run Code" feature... :)

Answer (score 0):

Please find the working code below

```
var f1, f2, result;
document.getElementById("add").onclick=function(){

f1= document.getElementById("f1").value;
f2= document.getElementById("f2").value;
result = f1+f2;

if(result!=null)
alert("Result = "+result);
}
```

Inorde to assign the value to a variable  there is no need to use return keyword . Also as you attaching   click event for each button seperatly in each of them you need code to display the result. Hope you can find & correct the other function as above.

Answer (score 0):

you have some error in your code:
1- you are returning value but never use it.
2- your function definition need ()
3- yo should to convert input values to int
then this will work for you

```
var f1, f2, result;
document.getElementById("add").onclick=function(){
    f1= document.getElementById("f1").value;
    f2= document.getElementById("f2").value;
    result = parseInt(f1)+parseInt(f2);
    if(result!=null)
        alert("Result = "+result);
}
document.getElementById("sub").onclick=function(){
    f1= document.getElementById("f1").value;
    f2= document.getElementById("f2").value;
    result = parseInt(f1)-parseInt(f2);
    if(result!=null)
        alert("Result = "+result);
}
document.getElementById("multi").onclick=function(){
    f1= document.getElementById("f1").value;
    f2= document.getElementById("f2").value;
    result = parseInt(f1)*parseInt(f2);
    if(result!=null)
        alert("Result = "+result);
}
document.getElementById("div").onclick=function(){
    f1= document.getElementById("f1").value;
    f2= document.getElementById("f2").value;
    result = parseInt(f1)/parseInt(f2);
    if(result!=null)
        alert("Result = "+result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />  
</head>
<body>
<h1>Calculator</h1>
<input id="f1" />
<input id="f2" />
<button id="add">Add</button>
<button id="sub">Sub</button>
<button id="multi">Multi</button>
<button id="div">Div</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
var f1, f2, result;
document.getElementById("add").onclick = function () {
    f1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("f1").value);
    f2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("f2").value);
    result = f1 + f2;
    showResult();
}
document.getElementById("sub").onclick = function () {
    f1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("f1").value);
    f2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("f2").value);
    result = f1 - f2;
    showResult();
}
document.getElementById("multi").onclick = function () {
    f1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("f1").value);
    f2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("f2").value);
    result = f1 * f2;
    showResult();
}
document.getElementById("div").onclick = function () {
    f1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("f1").value);
    f2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("f2").value);
    result = f1 / f2;
    showResult();
}
function showResult() {
    alert("Result = " + result);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```